# Django default field validatio getting skipped in ajax calls

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, forms, validation

I have wasted a lot of time on this and finally seeking help in this great forum. I have am a django starter and working on a model form that takes address details from user and validates by overriding clean method for fields.Issues started cropping up when I tried to use ajax where the ajax call is conveniently skipping form validation for some reason. Please guide me, I cant figure out why the is_valid() value in my view is coming True though the view function calls on the AdrressForm object containing all validation methods.

```
// IN my views.py// 
@transaction.atomic
def update_profile_address(request):
    user = request.user
    if request.method == 'POST':
        address_form = AddressForm(request.POST, instance=user.profile)
        if address_form.is_valid():
            address_form.save()
            response_data = {"success_message": " Details Saved Successfully."}
            return HttpResponse(
            json.dumps(response_data),
            content_type="application/json"
            )
    else:
        address_form = AddressForm(instance=user.profile)
    return render(request, 'update_profile_address.html', {
        'address_form': address_form,
        })

//in my forms.py //
class AddressForm(forms.ModelForm): 
    class Meta: 
        model = Profile
        fields = ('address_city', 'address_state','address_country','address_pin')
        labels = { 
                    'address_city': 'City', 
                    'address_state':'State', 
                    'address_country': 'Country', 
                    'address_pin':'Pincode',
        }
        widgets = { 
            'address_city': forms.TextInput(
                attrs={ 'required': True, 'placeholder': 'your city'}
            ),
            'address_state': forms.TextInput(
                attrs={'required': True, 'placeholder': 'Madhya Pradesh'}
            ),
            'address_country': forms.TextInput(
                attrs={ 'required': True, 'placeholder': 'India'}
            ),
            'address_pin': forms.TextInput(
                attrs={ 'required': True, 'placeholder': 'your pin code'}
            ),
        }

        def clean_address_city(self): 
            address_city = self.cleaned_data['address_city']
            print(address_city)
            if not address_city.isalpha(): 
                raise  forms.ValidationError('Location can be alphabetic only.')
            return address_city

        def clean_address_state(self): 
            address_state = self.cleaned_data['address_state']
            if not address_state.isalpha(): 
                raise  forms.ValidationError('State can be alphabetic only.')
            return address_state

        def clean_address_country(self): 
            address_country = self.cleaned_data['address_country']
            if not address_country.isalpha(): 
                raise  forms.ValidationError('Country name can be alphabetic only.')
            return address_country

        def clean_address_pin(self): 
            address_pin = self.cleaned_data['address_pin']
            if not address_pin.isnumeric(): 
                raise  forms.ValidationError('Pin can be numeric only.')
            return address_pin

// ajax call //
    $("#tab2_2").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault(); 
        $('li.active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            success: function(data){ 
                document.getElementById("inner-content").innerHTML = data;
                 $('#address-form').submit(function(event){ 
                    event.preventDefault();
                    console.log('form submission prevented');
                    address_form_submit();

                })

            }

        });
    }); 

    function address_form_submit(){ 
        console.log($('#address-form').serialize());

        $.ajax({
                    url:"{% url 'update_profile_address' %}", 
                    type:"POST",
                    /*data : { address_city : $('#address_city').val(),
                            address_state: $('#address_state').val(),
                            address_country:$('#address_country').val(),
                            address_pin:$('#address_pin').val(),
                            csrfmiddlewaretoken : '{{ csrf_token }}'
                    }, */
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: $('#address-form').serialize(),
                    success: function(json){ 
                    console.log(json);
                    var msg_box = document.getElementById('message-box');
                    if (json.success_message) { 
                        msg_box.innerHTML = json.success_message;
                        $('#message-box').addClass("alert-success");


                    };


                    }
                })

    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indentation issue. Your clean methods are inside the Meta class.